# Jenkins and Findbugs

Tags: jenkins, findbugs

My requirement is to display the findbugs total, fixed and new warnings in email using jenkins. I am using static_analysis.jelly script through email-ext plugin but I am not able to get the count. this is the code I am using:

```xml
<j:set var="fb" value="${it.getAction('hudson.plugins.findbugs.FindBugsResultAction')}" />
<table width="100%">
   <tr><td colspan="2"><b>Findbugs Result</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Total:</td><td>${fb.result.numberOfWarnings}</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Fixed:</td><td>${fb.result.numberOfFixedWarnings}</td></tr>
   <tr><td>New:</td><td>${fb.result.numberOfNewWarnings}</td></tr>
   <tr><td colspan="2"><a href="${rooturl}${build.url}/findbugs">View Report</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

I am using Jenkins version 1.5.42. All the reports are generated through mavens correctly. Any clue is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sanjiv